# Objective-c: passing data from UITable to ViewController with prepareForSegue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

this is my very first app and, basically, this part consists in passing data from a UItableView to a second View Controll. I managed to learn how to pass data from a simple NSarray (also in a UITable), but my goal is to pass values from a NSDictionary. Everything is set up, but I can't figure out how to write the PrepareForSegue method properly. The app runs, but the label on the "DetailView" stays empty. What I got so far:

```
@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _citySpots = @{@"Bars" : @[@"Hurricane", @"Black Swan", @"Texas"],
                       @"Clubs" : @[@"Electric Wizard", @"Offspring", @"The Tunnel"],
                       @"Restaurants" : @[@"Nando's", @"1/2 Burguer", @"Satellite"],
                       };

        _sectionTitles = [[_citySpots allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }
```

PrepareForSegue Method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"spotsDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSString *sectionTitle = [_sectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

         NSArray *citySpots = [_citySpots objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        destViewController.receiver = [citySpots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

And the receiver(header):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *receiver;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *spot;

@end
```

Main:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()


@end

@implementation DetailViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _receiver.text =_spot;
}
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks

Comment: `destViewController.receiver = [citySpots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` => `destViewController.spot = [citySpots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, Larme, the label is still empty...

Comment: But in `viewDidLoad`, is `_receiver` `nil`? Does `_spot` have the correct value?

Comment: I just changed what you suggested (receiver->spot). The viewDidLoad of the DetailViewController is still like this:

_receiver.text =_spot;

Comment: Honestly I don't get it, everything seems ok, i just can't trace the problem...Anyone has a different view?

Comment: Well...The problem was that I forgot to name de segue identifier in the storyboard...Tricky stuff, IOS :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setters:

```
[destViewController setReceiver:[citySpots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[destViewController setSpot:[citySpots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex, but I managed to figured out: the segue didn't had identifier...Rookie mistake :) The problem is solved (and I thought I commented that yesterday, it seems the comment wasnt saved...Sorry about that